# Why is $HOME being unset within vim within a tmux session

Tags: vim, tmux

Up-to-date Fedora 19, when I launch tmux and at the bash prompt and type:

```
echo $HOME
```

my $HOME environment variable is displayed.  If I then launch vim (with and without --noplugin -U none) and type:

```
:echo $HOME
```

my $HOME environment variable is NOT displayed.

What configuration should I change so that vim knows about $HOME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
export HOME
```

to your ~/.bashrc.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this seems to resolve my issue.  I'm not sure I understand why this helps.  Can you explain it?  $HOME does seem to be set, as revealed by echo $HOME at the bash prompt.

Comment: When bash is run, it sets the values of several environment variables including HOME. When bash runs a command in a new environment, that new environment inherits much of the environment of the parent shell, but only the definitions of those variables that were marked for export.

In your case, HOME was not marked for export so its definition was not included in the environment created for vim. Bash defines HOME for itself, so the value is always available at a shell prompt.